# writing a batch file for loop to rename and move files

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, file-rename

I've never used Windows `cmd` scripting before; I'm trying to write a batch script, What I need to do:

I have a lot of folders, named numerically. Each one contains a file. All the files have the same name.

e.g.

```
folder1\file   folder2\file
```

I want to rename and move the files, so they are named numerically and in the one folder

e.g.

```
newfolder\file1   newfolder\file2
```

My script for two test folders is:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,2) DO
(
move "folder%%A\file.txt" "newfolder\file%%A.txt"
)
```

I suspect this is all wrong. I get "the syntax of the command is incorrect".

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour] as recommended. Please be concise and don't repeat yourself (e.g. repeatedly stating that this is your first script), as others have to spend their free time reading all that information which doesn't help to make them understand the problem at hand. It is also not necessary to state that you think that something is wrong/not working, you would not be here otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Just move the opening parenthesis on the first line:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,2) DO (
move "folder%%A\file.txt" "newfolder\file%%A.txt"
)
```

Newlines aren't as invisible to the batch interpreter as in most other languages, meaning you have to explicitly tell it to look on the following lines.